# How is the final kinetic energy of satellite zero at max height?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, energy-conservation

Lets say a satellite is projected vertically with sqrt(gR).and it reaches a max height, so we have to calculate the max height.
in our class, our professor using conservation of energy , solved the example but in the final mechanical energy term , he said the final kinetic energy of satellite will be zero. My question is that how can final kinetic energy of that object will be zero?if it was zero , wont it fall back to the ground?

Comment: FYI, a "satellite" is an object, either man-made or a natural body, that orbits some other astronomical object. A better word for an object that is, as you say, _projected_ vertically from the surface would be "projectile."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will fall back to Earth (given the initial velocity you mentioned.)  But that's to be expected, since you can't get a satellite into orbit by launching it vertically.  Presumably this is a simplified example to illustrate conservation of energy, and not a realistic scenario about a real satellite.